# Show highest value after matching different columns

Tags: excel

I got a bit of a problem here

I got 4 columns (A,B,D,E) and i need some stuff:

Column A and D got references (D is bigger than A);
COlumn B and E got prices, refering to A and D, respectively;

First of all, check if a certain value in column A exists in Column D. 
If that happens, i need somehow to check which is the highest value between B & E of the same string and display it in Column C

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX with VLOOKUP:

```
=MAX(B1,VLOOKUP(A1,D:E,2,FALSE))
```

[image]